# How do I beat the feeding kids minigame?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-2

There's this weird minigame where i have to constantly feed 6 kids, but even if I feed them all nothing happens.

There's a kid on the top of the screen who is crying and then he turns gray or something.

How am I supposed to actually beat the minigame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the previous comment said, you don't actually beat them (though so long as you at least make an attempt, the mini game will last longer, and you're able to see that entire piece of story rather than just the beginning of it). It only serves the purpose to give some background, such as in one of the mini games (play'ed as Freddy Fazebear), you follow around the marionette with someone (possibly Freddy) vaguely spelling S A V E T H E M over and over in the background (so long as you listen closely it shouldn't be hard to make out ^^). Some may spectate that by 'Save them', it's talking about the children trapped inside the suits, in which they cannot escape, and are in need of a saviour. In another mini game, this time you're playing as the marionette, starting out by giving presents to little boys and girls. It soon turns into you having to give life to the four main animatronics, Freddy, Chika, Bonnie, and Foxy, implying that the Marionette stuffed the souls of the dead children into the suit (Whether his intentions were good or bad is unknown to the player, though most assume it to be bad since they're stuck to forever suffer and rot within). Each mini game is different, and gives you another clue as to what happened with the 5 dead children, alongside what is happening in Freddy's Pizzeria (or, in the second games case, diner). Hope this helped!!! ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's telling you a story. In two of the mini games (that I have seen) you play as Toy Freddy. You are following the puppet, and as you walk Freddy is spelling S.A.V.E. T.H.E.M. Save them. Save who? That is another story.